# Determine if the ring $R=\{a,b,c,d\}$ is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Determine if the ring $R=\{a,b,c,d\}$ is a field given the following tables. [image]

A ring $R$ is a field if the pair $(R \setminus \{e\}, \cdot)$ is commutative.

So looking at the table it seems that $b = e$ here. We have that $$a \cdot c=a = c \cdot a \\ a\cdot d=a = d \cdot a \\ c \cdot d=c =d \cdot c$$ so it would seem that $(R \setminus \{b\}, \cdot)$ commutes?

Comment: It looks like $e$ is referring to the additive identity?  In that case, you have the wrong $e$.  Then you need to check (1) $R\setminus \{e\}$ is closed under multiplication and then (2) it's commutative.

Comment: With $e=b$ I was referring to the multiplicative identity. Isn’t $b$ the multiplicative identity or am I mistaken?

Comment: The multiplicative identity is $b$, but if that's your $e$, then your criterion for a field is wrong.  Ultimately, a ring $(R, +, \cdot, 0, 1)$ is a field if and only if $(R\setminus \{0\}, \cdot, 1)$ is an abelian group.  In your case, $c\cdot c = a$ is a problem for this.

Comment: Some info: a field that has $4$ elements has characteristic $2$ which means that all $x+x=0$ for every $x$. So on the diagonal of the addition table of such field we can only expect element $0$.